# Passing the name of a pandas dataframe column to a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a function that takes the name of a column and splits the dataframe based on the values of that column. I have the following

`df_split = df[df.a == 1]`

I'm trying to implement the following idea

```
def f(df,column_name): 
  df_split = df[df.column_name == 1]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `df_split = df[df[column_name] == 1]`
is this what you want? if not, please give more clarity on the question

Comment: so, posting this in answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the function to following:

```
def f(df,column_name): 
  df_split = df[df[column_name] == 1]
  return df_split
```

df.column_name will work only if the dataframe really have a column labelled as `column_name` so don't use it inside the function